# How to only allow the current month in Month Calender

Tags: c#, monthcalendar

I'm trying to get the month calender in my windows form to only allow the user to select days in the current month, my program uses the day selected to retrieve a line from a text file, but obviously it will read the line for day 1 or 20 etc. regardless of the month.

How do i set the properties so the monthcalender is locked to current month??

something along the lines of the below

```
monthCalendar.MinDate = DateTime.CurrentMonth.DaysInMonth.First;
monthCalender.MaxDate = DateTime.CurrentMonth.DaysInMonth.Last;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstDayInMonth and lastDayInMonth you ccan get with this code:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime firstDayInMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
DateTime lastDayInMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month));
```

Comment: Thanks a mill that worked perfect. i was close i had tried  DateTime first = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month but when i got to Month it asked for int year so i stopped and said no that must be wrong. Thanks